# filtrar o nome de um obj de acordo com o maior numero

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu consegui que o programa mostre o maior valor dentro de um obj. Porém, o exercício pede que eu divulgue o nome do obj de maior valor.

```
let maior = 0;

for (let item of obras){
  if (maior < item.valor) {
    maior = item.valor;
  } if (item.valor = maior){
    console.log(item.nome);
  } 
}
```

O segundo `if` esta errado, porém eu não pensei em nada para resolvê-lo.

Comment: Ao invés de salvar `item.valor` em `maior`, não é melhor salvar o objeto inteiro? Aí no `if` você compara `maior.valor` ao invés de só `maior`. E fora do `for` faz um `console.log(maior.nome)`

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando as ideias do @Rafael Tavares, uma maneira de resolver seria:

```
const obras = [
    {valor: 1,
    nome: "um"},
    {valor: 2,
    nome: "dois"}
]

if (obras.length > 0) {
    let maior = obras[0]

    for (let i = 1; i < obras.length;i++){
        if (obras[i].valor > maior.valor) {
            maior = obras[i]
        }
    }
    console.log(`A obra de maior valor é: ${maior.nome}`)
} else {
    console.log('Não é possível determinar o maior valor')
}
```

Em meu código eu estou verificando o tamanho do conjunto de obras antes de poder determinar o maior.

Isso é importante pois caso o conjunto esteja vazio eu não posso determinar qual o maior valor. Em seu exemplo você está atribuindo um valor zero à variável`"maior"` que não faz parte do conjunto de obras, que neste caso pode dar um falso positivo. Imagine que no conjunto só existem valores negativos, neste caso o seu programa vai exibir um valor errado.

Outra coisa que eu fiz é atribuir o valor de obra[0] à variável maior, e inicio a iteração (repetição) a partir do segundo elemento. (normalmente o laço `for` se inicia com o índice zero).

Assim ao percorrer todo o conjunto de dados temos o resultado esperado.